# 99 kvm/qemu/virt-manager problems

Tags: kvm, qemu, virt-manager

**Specs**

- Host system: Kernel: 5.15.28-1-MANJARO
- virt-manager version 4.0.0
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H

Questions should be specific and address only one problem etc.. i know.
But this program has me frustrated beyond sanity and I don't get, why anybody would advertise it. So, lacking alternatives, I'm flipping tables here.

**First guest: Ubuntu 20.04.**

1. Issue: Sharing data

   *Disclaimer: Pasting text (and only text) works both ways, flawlessly.*

   I set up a shared folder, following [this link](https://%20%20%20hs://ostechnix.com/setup-a-shared-folder-between-kvm-host-and-guest/)

   One day, I simply couldn't mount the shared folder anymore. Instead I got this error

   ```
   mount: /home/path/to/share: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.
   ```

   In it's place Drag'n'Drop from Host to guest magically started to work, placing documents in the Guest-Download Folder. The other way around doesn't work, however, so I have no way to share from guest to host.
2. I can't create snapshots while guest is running:

   ```
   libvirt.libvirtError: Requested operation is not valid: migration with virtiofs device is not supported
   ```
3. Issue: USB redirecting

   I can redirect one specific USB key. If I then want to exchange this key for another one, I get this error:

   ```
   spice-client-error-quark: Could not auto-redirect Generic Mass Storage [058f:6387] at 3-5: Error setting USB device node ACL:
   'Error Failed to drop capabilities: -3' (0)
   ```

   This is especially problematic with a USB to Ethernet adapter. Do I really have to go through the USB redirection menu, every
   time I plug in a new USB key?!

**Second guest (should be) WindowsXP 64bit**

1. Issue: I can't even load the .iso, as it tells me the permission is denied. (I chmod 777'ed the iso to no avail)
2. Out of frustration i tried VirtualBox, as this used to work in the past. Thanks to virt-manager, i now get an error *there*,
   saying i should recompile my host kernel.

And these are just the open questions right now, not to speak of all the steps and work-arounds I **already** had to do to get it running in
the first place or glitches that arise an vanish ad-hoc (Webcam not working on host anymore, Network connection in guest not
available from one second to the other, needing to separately install virt-viewer for multiple monitors, etc.)

Maybe I'm dumb or not Linuxing properly, but tbh I regret so much, to ever have started with virt-manager. So once I'm done setting the tables right again, I'll migrate to VirtualBox, where stuff works out of the (no pun intended) box - and keep wondering why everybody seems to want to go the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As assumed, the solution was: Switch Hypervisor. Gnome Boxes Runs .qcow2 files out of the box, is more user friendly and stable.